# How do I troubleshoot a Windows 7 freeze or slowness?

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the first steps for diagnosing a slow machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/26862/what-are-the-first-steps-for-diagnosing-a-slow-machine)

I have a new pc with windows 7 which freezes randomly. I hit every single key on the keyboard and it works again. Is there a way to prevent windows 7 from freezing?