# How can I make Windows 7 show thumbnails for MKV files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, codec, matroska

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and have installed the latest Haali Media Splitter.

How can I make Windows Explorer show thumbnails for MKV files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Icaros 1.2.5 works, if it doesn't work alone, install Shark007 Codec Pack!

http://www.majorgeeks.com/Icaros_d7220.html

http://shark007.net/

Comment: Confirming that Icaros 3.1.0 is working well on Windows 7. Just install, launch the (slick looking) configurator, replace the default set of filetypes with `mkv`, and click the 'deactivated' under 'Thumbnailing' to toggle it. Thumbnails will start being generated immediately.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the *Haali Media Splitter Properties*.
2. Click the *Options* tab, expand *Explorer integration* and select *Enable thumbnails extraction*:

   [image: Haali Media Splitter Properties]
3. Set the value to *Yes*. You might want to configure the *Thumbnails offset* (a milliseconds value) to say, 10000 to give you more representative thumbnails.
4. Restart the machine.

Comment: tried, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to work at first with Windows 7 64-bit.

You need to add the following lines to the registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mkv\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11D1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}] 
@="{c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mkv\ShellEx\{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}] 
@="{c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}"
```

Curiously, a whole day after applying those changes, thumbnails for mkv files began to show up in Explorer, so it does work (with Haali MKV Splitter on Windows 7 64-bit systems).

Comment: where does `{c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}` come from?  Looking at my reg it's `{9DBD2C50-62AD-11D0-B806-00C04FD706EC}` for .mpg and .avi

Comment: tried both, restarted, they don't work... or maybe i really need to wait 'a whole day'?

Comment: wow, it works, but without offset it's kindda useless.  80% of them are just... black

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to change this. It seems use the same offset no matter what value I set in haali options.

Comment: I think it stops working again, sad.

Answer (score 1):

[MediaPreview](http://babelsoft.net/products.htm) as suggested per [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5908599/media-preview-adds-windows-explorer-thumbnails-to-nearly-any-video-file) does a fine job, also for other formats such as `ogg` and `3gp`.

Answer (score 0):

It's problem caused by Windows 64 bit. Download [K-lite Codec Pack for 64bit](http://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm) and everything works out fine. Tried.
Note: Use it together with K-Lite Codec PAck for 32bit for best result.