# Tracking down System CPU usage

Tags: windows-xp, kernel, cpu-usage

My System process (Not system idle process) is using 5-10% CPU constantly.

Using Sysinternals process explorer, I've identified the offending thread as having an ID of 8 and the following stack trace:

```
ntkrnlpa.exe!NtBuildNumber+0x33
ntkrnlpa.exe!MmIsDriverVerifying+0xb9a
ntkrnlpa.exe!ZwYieldExecution+0x941
ntkrnlpa.exe!KeRemoveQueue+0x276
ntkrnlpa.exe!MmTrimAllSystemPagableMemory+0x669b
```

How can I take the above information and determine which DLL/Driver/??? is the culprit?

**Edit:** Interestingly, after a reboot, the System process is still eating up CPU (It's the same Thread Id (8) which is using CPU but I'm assuming that's pure coincidence). The stack trace, however, is noticeably different:

```
ntkrnlpa.exe!KiDispatchInterrupt+0xa7
ntkrnlpa.exe!ZwYieldExecution+0x3744
ntkrnlpa.exe!NlsOemLeadByteInfo+0x19a74
ntkrnlpa.exe!PsRemoveCreateThreadNotifyRoutine+0x214
ntkrnlpa.exe!KiDispatchInterrupt+0x72e
```

Comment: How to trace System Interrupts and high DPC....http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [configure your symbols](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SetUpYourSystemToUseMicrosoftsPublicSymbolServer.aspx) so that you get more useful information, also look into the stacks if you can.

Other than that, you can [try this procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/205298/windows-7-freezes/205307#205307) so that I could try to look into it (or you could yourself)... :)

Comment: Thanks. I've added symbol support and edited the stack trace to include the additional information.

Comment: @Basiclife: With the other procedure you can figure out which interrupts cause this behavior in System.