# Windows 7 freezes randomly

Tags: windows-7, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I troubleshoot a Windows 7 freeze or slowness?](https://superuser.com/questions/205298/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness)

I have an install of Windows 7 that is a year and a half old. I never experienced any issues with it until the last few weeks. It started freezing from time to time. When I spend the whole evening on my computer, it may freeze 5 times or might not freeze at all, I can't find a pattern.

I read somewhere that it might be the latest updates, so I uninstalled everything since beginning of October (a bit before it started to happen.)
But it just happened again.

Event log and reliability are empty don't have any error in and I'm out of ideas on how to diagnose this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please try [How do I troubleshoot a Windows 7 freeze or slowness?](http://superuser.com/questions/205298/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you done any ram upgrades recently? if you have test them out individually that should determine which ram is bad. Memtest is a good tool to use as suggested. Have you updated any drivers as well? sometimes drivers can conflict with other devices that may cause your machine to hang. But in most cause ram would be the best and easiest test. Software are a lot harder to find.

good luck

Comment: No ram upgrade for two years. I ran memtest and it found some errors, so I removed one of the memory module and hope it will not crash again. Thanks

Comment: So far it didn't crash, so that must be it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try running a software as memtest to check your DIMMs. Could be one of them that is corrupted and forces Windows to freeze.