# Windows vista sfc /scannow unable to repair

Tags: windows, windows-vista, repair

After noticing that a computer I use at work - running an up-to-date Windows Vista - started freezing randomly I ran some tests and ended up with doing a `sfc /scannow`.

This results in three files reported with "**Unable to repair member-file**". I've read that it is safe to ignore one of them (settings.ini) but the other two seem to need replacement: wabimp.dll and mprddm.dll.mui.

I have two questions that I haven't managed to find the answers for:

1. Where can I find these exact versioned files if I don't have an install dvd (OS was pre-installed and no installation media is present)?
2. If I manage to find replacement files how do I proceed to replace them? (Since it is windows I assume I can't just replace them in the folder-tree).

Comment: The quickest way is to locate an installation DVD for the version of Vista you have.

Answer (score 0):

1. Its best to get the needed files from another Vista PC with the same bit and Service Pack level and same windows patches applied. Search the hard drive for them. Windows service packs, security updates or other windows patches can possibly change the version of those files, so sourcing them from an install dvd will likely have different versions than you need.

EDIT:

Those 2 dll files are not critical and should not cause your issue. wabimp is for the windows address book, and mprddm is for routing and remote access. [See this link for freezing issues](https://superuser.com/questions/205298/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness/205307#205307)

Comment: Is there anyway (but trial and error) to find what update package contains the exact file-version?

Comment: That would be a very hard task, it would be easier to re-install the OS. Check my edit to my answer.