# My PC freezes during network related stuff

Tags: windows-7, freeze

My PC freezes in certain occasions which almost always have something to do with network. For example when connecting to a VPN or DSL or when Kerio client connects to server.

Whats wrong?

PC specs:

```
win 7
AMD athlon x2 5600
2GB 886 ddr 2
3 hard disks
```

Comment: If you describe what freezes, the question would be more complete. If it is only net dependant things. Also you could look at the ammount of paging going on to disk (2g ram), because that will slow things a lot.  Check also the network tab in the resource monitor . To provide more information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I troubleshoot a Windows 7 freeze or slowness?](http://superuser.com/questions/205298/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness)

Comment: Probably not so duplicate, because this is more related with "network related stuff" (I mean it's a part of that question, but not the same question)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible things that can cause it. But first of all, please check your network settings and make sure they are correct.

- Network driver problem. In that case updating driver may help you. Or if it started to happen after update then rolling back the driver will help.
- Software problem. Some software (e.g. network monitors, tools) can install drivers, change network settings. It can cause the same problem especially if that driver is not compatible with your hardware. In this case removing that software will help you.
- Malware problem. For example - a malware with BitCoin miner, bruteforce and so on. When you connect to network, it starts mining bitcoin and uses your CPU intensively, thus making computer slower. Scan your computer for malware using strong antiviruses.